# Outlook VSTO add context menu item

Tags: c#, vsto

I am trying to add a menu item to the attachment context menu. The problem is that the item does not show up. I've seen some examples where they say that this code should work:

```
this.Application.AttachmentContextMenuDisplay += new ApplicationEvents_11_AttachmentContextMenuDisplayEventHandler(ThisAddIn_AttachmentContextMenuDisplay);

private void ThisAddIn_AttachmentContextMenuDisplay(CommandBar commandBar, AttachmentSelection attachments)
{
    if (attachments.Count > 0)
    {
        var cbc = commandBar.Controls.Add(
                  MsoControlType.msoControlButton,
                  missing, missing, missing, true);

        cbc.Caption = "My custom item";
    }
}
```

The event `ThisAddIn_AttachmentContextMenuDisplay` is fired and the attachment count is larger than zero, but the menu item is not displayed.

Strange thing is that if I call `commandBar.ShowPopup();` then the menu item will show (note the missing icons), but when it is clicked the context menu will show a second time:

[image: Context menu when calling commandBar.ShowPopup();]

Without calling commandBar.ShowPopup(); the context menu looks as usual, but it is missing my custom item:

[image: Context menu without calling commandBar.ShowPopup()]

EDIT: I am using Visual Studio 2013 and Outlook 2010

Comment: Have you solved this issue for outlook 2016 ? , i am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Command bars were deprecated and shouldn't be used any longer except running controls programmatically (see ExecuteMso). You need to use the Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI) instead. See [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx) for more information.

Read more about the Fluent UI in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

If you need to hide or show some controls depending on the context you can handle ribbon callbacks where you can decide whether a control should be shown to a user or not.

Comment: Is there an example somewhere that shows me how to simply add an item to the attachment context menu? It looks like a simple task and those Fluent UI articles are really a pain to read.

Comment: Does this still apply to Outlook 2016?

Comment: Ya rather than posting links, better post some sample code